# Network Manager requested to „sleep“ every 30 minutes - wifi drops

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

> Intel Joule 570 - ubuntu 16.04: network manager gets a request exactly
>   every 30min to „sleep“  (syslog: NetworkManager[888]:  
>   [1518429735.9501] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled:
>   yes) )

=> wifi connection goes down…

What can trigger this behaviour? The wifi connection itself is stable and performs well, no issues.

Power management - tried to disable all potential triggers:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
sudo systemctl mask upower.service (systemctl status upower.service => Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad) - Active: inactive (dead)
```

- wifi: all power safe options disabled

Any ideas where to look - trying the avoid wifi going down…nothing I found so far (tried almost everything) did stop the weird behaviour..

Thanks in advance - Best 
milan

Details: 
- need to work on `cli`

```
4.4.0-1000-joule #0+joule21-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 16 14:46:45 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS - Release: 16.04 - Codename: xenial
```

Comment: Did you ever get a response or a fix? I recently update to the 4.17 kernel and NetworkManager seems to drop off about every 30 minutes. May or may not be the same problem as I don't know how to discover what is causing it.

Comment: can you write an answer, in order to help other people which would have the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

OP provided an answer as part of their question:

> SOLVED: guess the “GUI” environment triggered the request to sleep after 30min -
>
> given that I run the Joule headless: disabling `Gnome` and `lightdm`
>   did the trick - system up and running for hours (didn’t reverse the
>   masking of sleep, suspend, hibernate, hybrid…).

Comment: With all power-management settings set to disabled, these suspends every 30 minutes suddenly started occurring for no obvious reason. No lightdm installed, but heaps of gnome stuff. Purging each and every package matching `*gnome*` appears to have made the issue go away. Would had preferred a fix less intrusive than removing the graphical environment, but the workaround is good enough for de facto headless systems.